How to obtain stable ADC readings from a DC battery using EK-TM4C123GXL(ARM Cortex M4)?
I am working on a project using the Texas Instruments EK-TM4C123GXL LaunchPad to measure the voltage of a breadboard power supply module(hw-131) . I am using the onboard ADC module to read the voltage, but I am facing some issues:

Problem Description:

I have connected the 3.3V terminal of the power supply module  to the ADC input pin (PE3/AIN0) of the TM4C123GXL.
The ADC conversion is done using the internal 3.3V reference voltage.
I have already confirmed with a multimeter that the voltage input to the TM4C123GXL from the power module is stable at 2.8 volts, with fluctuations of no more than ±0.05 volts.
During testing, I noticed that the ADC output values are unstable and fluctuate significantly, even when the input voltage remains steady.


What I've Tried:

I checked the ADC configuration and clock settings, and I have ensured that appropriate sampling time and resolution are being used.
I also implemented averaging of multiple samples, but this did not completely eliminate the fluctuations.


Relevant Code:

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/adc.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"
#include "utils/uartstdio.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"

#define NUM_SAMPLES 8

// Function to configure UART0 for communication
void ConfigureUART(void)
{
    // Enable UART0 and GPIOA peripherals
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);

    // Configure PA0 and PA1 as UART pins
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA0_U0RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA1_U0TX);
    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);

    // Initialize UART0 with a baud rate of 115200
    UARTStdioConfig(0, 115200, SysCtlClockGet());
}

// ADC0 interrupt handler
void ADC0IntHandler(void)
{
    // Clear the ADC interrupt flag
    ADCIntClear(ADC0_BASE, 0);

    uint32_t ui32ADC0Value[NUM_SAMPLES];
    uint32_t ui32Sum = 0;
    uint32_t i = 0;

    // Get the ADC sequence data
    ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE, 0, ui32ADC0Value);

    // Sum the ADC values
    while(i < NUM_SAMPLES){
        ui32Sum += ui32ADC0Value[i];
        i++;
    }

    // Calculate the average ADC value
    uint32_t ui32Average = ui32Sum / NUM_SAMPLES;

    // Print the average ADC value to the UART
    UARTprintf("ADC Average Value: %d\n", ui32Average);

    // Calculate the input voltage in volts (assuming 3.3V reference voltage)
    float voltage = (ui32Average * 3.3) / 4096.0;
    uint32_t v_int_part = voltage; // Integer part of the voltage
    uint32_t v_frac_part = (voltage - v_int_part) * 1000; // Fractional part in millivolts

    // Print the calculated voltage to the UART
    UARTprintf("Input Voltage: %d.%03d V\n", v_int_part, v_frac_part);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Set the system clock to 50MHz (200MHz PLL / 4)
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);

    // Configure UART for debugging
    ConfigureUART();

    // Enable the ADC0 and GPIOE peripherals
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_ADC0);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOE);

    // Wait for the peripherals to be ready
    while(!SysCtlPeripheralReady(SYSCTL_PERIPH_ADC0) || !SysCtlPeripheralReady(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOE))
    {
    }

    // Configure PE3 as ADC input
    GPIOPinTypeADC(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);

    // Set the ADC clock source and rate
    ADCClockConfigSet(ADC0_BASE, ADC_CLOCK_SRC_PIOSC | ADC_CLOCK_RATE_FULL, 8);

    // Configure ADC sequence 0 to be triggered by the processor
    ADCSequenceConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, ADC_TRIGGER_PROCESSOR, 0);

    // Configure all 8 steps in the sequence to sample from CH0 (PE3)
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 0, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 1, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 2, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 3, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 4, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 5, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 6, ADC_CTL_CH0);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 0, 7, ADC_CTL_CH0 | ADC_CTL_IE | ADC_CTL_END); // Enable interrupt on last step

    // Enable ADC sequence 0
    ADCSequenceEnable(ADC0_BASE, 0);

    // Clear any pending ADC interrupts
    ADCIntClear(ADC0_BASE, 0);

    // Enable ADC interrupts
    ADCIntEnable(ADC0_BASE, 0);

    // Enable the ADC0 sequence 0 interrupt in the NVIC
    IntEnable(INT_ADC0SS0);

    // Set ADC0 sequence 0 interrupt priority to highest (0)
    IntPrioritySet(INT_ADC0SS0, 0x00);

    while(1)
    {
        // Trigger the ADC conversion
        ADCProcessorTrigger(ADC0_BASE, 0);

        // Delay to simulate some processing time
        SysCtlDelay(SysCtlClockGet() / 6);
    }
}



My Questions:

Are there any methods to stabilize these readings, such as better software techniques?
Do I need to make specific ADC configurations to stabilize the input signal?
What are the best practices for this type of application that you would recommend?


Circuit:

fluctuate data as shown:

when the power supply module ON

when the power supply module OFF]




It seems that power supply module OFF fluctuate more significantly than power supply module ON.
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

show us your circus diagram.

@ChristophRackwitz "circuit" you mean?

@U.Windl I have added a picture of the circuit in the fifth point. Apologies as I am a beginner, so I am using the simplest way to present my circuit. Thank you for your understanding.

@U.Windl in hindsight, maybe I should have.

That is not a circuit diagram.  Sketch it (just the part that relates to the source, the divider and the ADC, photo that and post it.  I see no voltage divider in the photo, the 3.3v output of your supply appears to be what you have connected to the ADC, not the battery as stated.  The MCU board dies not appear to be powered at all.

if the issue is the electrical side, i.e. finding out why the ADC is noisier than promised in the data sheet, perhaps [electronics.se] is a better fit.

Not seeing a 3.3V supply to the J1/1 pin in that picture, nor any voltage divider resistors

Neither the battery nor the regulated power supply should exhibit any significant noise.  If you are seeing "fluctuations" you are clearly not sampling the source you think you are.  The question should be about correctly reading the ADC, not about how to make it "stable".  Clearly you could make it stable by filtering or averaging as you tried, but you will only be getting a "stable" reading if something that is not what you intended to measure.  All that said "fluctuate significantly" is unclear - can you quantify that? With min, max, standard-deviation or a plot perhaps?

You interrupt handler is ill-advised.  It is doing work that should not be none in an interrupt handler (such as printing to the UART, floating point math).  Your average is only for 8 sample blocks.  If you need an average (you should not)  then a much longer moving average would be advised.  You don't need an interrupt handler for this.

@Clifford I have updated the circuit image and the problem description. Apologize to you, the circuit does not actually include any voltage divider resistors. I have corrected.

@PeteKirkham Apologize to you, the circuit does not actually include any voltage divider resistors. I have corrected.

@Clifford Printing to the UART so that I can't see the read of the conversion in serial terminal. floating point math is for calculating the voltage of the analog input so that I am able to check if the voltage ADC result meet my expectation(Close to the value I measured using the multimeter).

@Clifford I have added the data of fluctuation in the sixth.

a multimeter won't show you the kind of noise that shows up on an ADC. multimeters usually average/RMS over a fraction of a second. if that even moves by HALF A VOLT, you've got serious problems somewhere.

@陳軍翰 I understand that you may need to present the data, I am simply saying that you should not do that in the interrupt handler.  How to avoid that is the subject for a different question.  Floating point is not necessary.  For debug you could just output the ADC value and calculate your "expectation" in terms of ADC value.  Even without that floating point is easy to avoid uint32_t voltage_mv = (ui32Average * 3300u) / 4096u ;.

Either way, do not post pictures of plain text.  Had you posted the data as text it would be possible to numerically analyse it.  Also still no evidence if the divider you claim, though the voltage suggests there is one.

The use of floating point in an interrupt, on hardware with hardware floating point is dangerous.  The interrupt does not preserve FPU registers, so if an FPU operation in the main thread or a task thread is preempted, the result of that operation will be corrupted by the interrupt.

"fluctuations of no more than ±0.5 volts." half a volt variation is fare larger than your debug output indicates, and is worryingly large.  Atr you sure that is not ±50 millivolts?

perhaps it's time to recommend a proper course of study, or at least vocational training. there is clearly too much going on that poses a challenge.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your support!  I found out the code I have posted is not exactly the same as the code generating that output. The code generating that output miss "03" in the format-specifier. The result meet the expectation after putting "03" back.

The large fluctuations are errors in your debug output and not "real". For example when you have an ADC value 9 corresponding to (9 x 3.3) / 4096 = 0.007 Volts, your debug code is outputting 0.7 Volts.
It looks as if your UARTprintf function does not support the %03d format-specifier.  Or the code you have posted is not the same as the code generating that output.  Save yourself the trouble, and use integer arithmetic and output the value in millivolts.
Otherwise I would say that the raw ADC fluctuation is a plausible level electrical noise from your power supply, the MCU itself, or even cross-talk from the UART output.
Your attempt at averaging is ineffective, taking only 8 samples probably at a far higher frequency than the noise you are trying to remove.  A larger moving average or an average taken from many readings over a long period of perhaps 0.5 seconds, or even an FIR or IIR low-pass filter would produce far better results.  Either way your signal conditioning needs to be appropriate to the characteristics of the noise you are observing.  Note that such a filter will perform poorly if the sample rate is variable, which it will be if you attempt to output readings to the UART in the interrupt handler - just one more way your debug code will give you misleading results.
